# how to choose one object from a sprite as3

Tags: actionscript-3

How to choose one object(picture that loaded by file) from a sprite when it is several object on that?
I want to drag one that mouse clicked.

```
private var spstage1:Sprite = new Sprite();
private var vecpic1:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
private var iconpic1:iconpic=new iconpic(); 
spstage1.graphics.beginFill(0xcccccc);
spstage1.graphics.drawRect(250,100,450,668);
stage.addChild(spstage1);
spstage1.addChild(iconpic1);
iconpic1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, picclicked);

function picclicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var txtFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("picture", "*.jpg;*.png"); 
            //root.browseForOpen("Open", [txtFilter]); 
            file = new File(); 
            currentload="pic";
            file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, dirSelected); 
            file.browseForOpen("Select a picture",[txtFilter]);
            //
            /*file.browse();
            file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,onselect);*/
        }

protected function dirSelected(e:Event):void { 
                var re1:URLRequest=new URLRequest(file.nativePath);
                loader=new Loader();
                loader.load(re1);
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadCompletepic);
            }

function loadCompletepic(event:Event):void{
            var pic:BitmapData=new BitmapData(loader.width,loader.height,false);
            pic.draw(loader);
            bitmap=new Bitmap(pic);
            spstage1.addChild(bitmap);
            bitmap.x=ix;
            bitmap.y=iy;
            vecpic1.push(bitmap.name);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `MOUSE_DOWN` event listener to `spstage1`.
In the listener handler, check:

```
function clickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (evt.target is Bitmap) {
        // here you decide what you have clicked on.
        (evt.target as DisplayObject).startDrag(); // do the stuff for dragging etc.
    }
}
```

Here evt.target will be the object that is clicked.
All you have to do is to determine if it is the right object. In this example, it is just checked to be of the Bitmap type. If you have other Bitmaps in the container that don't need to be clicked, use other means, for example store the loaded object somewhere and then compare the target against all the stored objects. Or check for `bitmap.name` which you seem to already have, etc.